# Sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets

I want several client on one server together.I also need that server can answer every getInputStream.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SOCKET_PORT);
while (true)
{
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();            
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    while(true)
    {
        String inputLine;
        inputLine = in.readLine();
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(inputLine);
        PrintWriter pw;
        pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        pw.println(jsonObj.toJSONString()); 
    }
}
```

I want when client writes something in stream, server could catch that and answer it. It doesn`t work, cause when the stream is empty, the app breaks.

Comment: If I am not missing something, before processing 'inputLine' check if(inpultLine != null){....}.

Comment: `the app breaks` - What do you mean? Does it throw an exception? If so, what is the StackTrace? If not, what does it do EXACTLY.

Comment: So what you are trying to achieve is server responding to multiple clients?

Comment: i want that server can respond client request every time client sends without closing and reopening socket stream

Answer (score 0):

Start a New thread every time you receive a new tcp client

Comment: i am doing that also but when the thread is made, how can I listen every request from the client side?